# Maven assembly plugin including javadoc

Tags: maven

I'm trying to include the javadocs generated by the maven-javadoc-plugin within my assembly. But it seems that the javadoc is generated after the assembly is built. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to generate before the assembly is built.

Here is my javadoc plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm running the `mvn package` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the phase configuration to some earlier lifecycle phase. E.g. try prepare-package